# Bigcommerce PHP API: Get option values for each product SKU

Tags: bigcommerce

I am creating a wholesale, 'bulk' order form for our store, in which all of our products and their prices are listed in a grid, and the user fills in a 'Quantity' box. [Here is a screenshot what I have so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ctda6.png)

I iterate through the products, generating a row with the product name, then iterate through the SKUs of each product, generating a row for each option.

I need to replace the SKUs with the option names and values to which they correspond. I found [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php/issues/45) that addresses something similar, but not quite what I need. How do I find the option values using the SKUs?